# Is there any way to get the length of an array after you declare it in C?

Tags: c, arrays

For example a code like:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Is there anyway to get the 5 in arr[5]?
I haven't learnt C++ before.

Comment: Have you tried `sizeof`?  For an array that is an `int*`, I know that you can't.

Comment: Make up your mind.  You have a C tag on the question and you reference C++ in your post.

Comment: @donjuedo : _"an array that is an `int*`"_ is an oxymoron - a pointer is not an array.  here `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr) == 5`.

Comment: @Clifford, I am pretty sure you have a solid of C and how it handles types.  There's no need for me to split hairs about `array`.

Comment: I said that I haven't learned C++ before just in case people assumed I had learnt it.

Comment: @cinos : That is understood, but your question is tagged [C], so mentioning C++ is not relevant. Presumably you are equally inproficient in C?

Comment: @donjuedo  It is not splitting hairs. It is an important distinction, ant in the context of this question Irellavant.  Your comment is likely to do more to confuse than to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it by getting the array size and divide it by the size of a single element:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
size_t lengthOfArr = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) ;
```

Comment: "element" is more correct than "cell", if I'm not mistaken.  Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: `sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]` is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions)er.

Comment: idk @donjuedo, english is not my native language, so if instead it's your case, i'm absolutely trust it ahah

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` may be DRYer yet....

Comment: C spec uses "element": e.g. "Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array."

Comment: @Berto99, Your English is excellent -- I would not have guessed it's not your first.

Comment: oh already done, thanks for the advice  @donjuedo

Comment: A better answer would explain that `sizeof arr` returns the number of bytes in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much!